# Active Reports winforms viewer control hosted in WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, winforms-interop, activereports

There is currently [not an available WPF viewer for Active Reports 6](http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/131019/ShowPost.aspx).   I was attempting to use a host control to display the viewer in a interop host but I'm not having much luck.  Has anyone else attempted this successfully?  I can't even get the wrapper Viewer control to add to the project toolbox as a custom control at this point.  I'm hoping to avoid recreating the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing ActiveReports Viewer works fine in WPF. You can use the below XAML to host it in WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="ARViewerHostedInWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:arv="clr-namespace:DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Viewer;assembly=ActiveReports.Viewer6"  
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1">
            <arv:Viewer x:Name="ARViewer" Dock="Fill" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The following code in the code-behind of the XAML file will connect a report to the viewer in the XAML above and run it:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewActiveReport1 rpt = new NewActiveReport1();
        this.ARViewer.Document = rpt.Document;
        rpt.Run();
    }
}
```

I'm using the [currently available version of ActiveReports 6](http://www.datadynamics.com/ActiveReports) to test this.

Hope this helps!

```
Scott Willeke
GrapeCity
```